# Getting the sum of three rows from one column?

Tags: sql

I have a table, the data in it looks similar to this:

```
user  type       hours    used    --to make another column with this info    available

2334  sick       10.000   2.000                                              8.000
2334  vacation   48.000   56.000                                             -8.000
2334  personal   0        8.000                                              0
1356  sick       0        16.000                                             -16.000
1356  vacation   80.000   0                                                  80.000
1356  personal   14.000   14.000                                             0
4355  sick       4.000    1.000                                              3.000
4355  vacation   112.000  0                                                  112.000 
4355  personal   8.000    0                                                  8.000
```

I had to sum up the values in the hours column, but only for each user.  So user 2334 would have earned `58.000` hours, `10.000 + 48.000 + 0` but would have used `66.000` hours resulting in `-8.000` hours.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT user, SUM(hours) totalHours
FROM tableName
GROUP BY user
```

- [**SEE SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c6f9/1)

Comment: Alias for `SUM(hours)`? Otherwise a fine answer for a question that should not have needed to be asked.

Comment: Thank you for your help @John Woo, my questions was accidentally submitted before I finished asking. I appreciate your answer.